# Can UPnP Discovery be done from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, upnp

I'm working on a webpage on which I want to discover some UPnP devices, however the client maybe on a different VLAN than the server.  So, UPnP discovery needs to happen on the client.  Apparently UDP is not possible with Javascript.  Does anyone know if there is a way to do UPnP discovery from the client's browser?

Comment: I think very, very hardly without a plug-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript has no built-in raw networking capabilities. For example, you can't natively do pings. You can do a DIY ping/port scanner using the `img` tag, and setting the `src` attribute to a target and testing the response. But, other than that, you will need a plugin or ActiveX.

I would also suggest using Java.

Comment: That's what I thought, just thought I would get other's thoughts.